# Primefaces Schedule View Year

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is it possible to have Year view for primefaces schedule? By default month/week/day view are values, how can I have a year view for schedule?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot achieve it by using the original Primefaces schedule only...
Quote from the [primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/scheduleHome.jsf) :

> Schedule is highly customizable featuring various views (month, day, week),

Also, the official full calendar jQuery plugin (on which the Primefaces schedule is actually based) does not support this out of the box [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)

BUT... you can take a look at this : [Year View with 12 Mini-Calendars](http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=871) there is an unofficial way to achieve what you are looking for look at the attached .rar file (demos/agenda-views.html)
So you first need to integrate the full calendar jQuery plugin in your web app, then look at the patch...

So eventually it is possible...

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your update. Do you think primefaces in near future would support year or quarter view for schedule?

Comment: Don't think so, cause even the original full calendar plugin does not support it yet, its marked as "MaybePlugin", but I might be wrong...